# Issue creating test data for a method using userInfo.getUserId()

Tags: apex, unit-test, customer-community-plus

Im having issue testing 3 of my methods (which are all working properly on my community site), they all use the same query with userInfo.getUserId() to retrieve user Id.

For example :

```
public without sharing class GetLogo {
   
    @auraEnabled
    public static String getImage(){
        
        User u = [SELECT Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :userInfo.getUserId()];
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, parent.Logo__c FROM Account WHERE parentId = :u.Contact.AccountId];
        String logoUrl = acc.parent.Logo__c;
        return logoUrl;
        }
    }
```

To test this class I'm using the following atm:

```
@isTest
public class GetLogoTest {

    @isTest
    static void getImageTest() {

        Account acc1 = new Account (
        Name = 'newAcc1',
        Logo__c = 'testLogo',
        Sous_type__c = 'Groupe'
        );  
        insert acc1;
        Contact conCase = new Contact (
        AccountId = acc1.id,
        LastName = 'portalTestUserv1'
        );
        insert conCase;

        Profile prfile = [SELECT Id,name FROM Profile WHERE Name= 'Portail Client' LIMIT 1];

        User newUser1 = new User(
        profileId = prfile.id,
        username = 'newUser@yahoo.com',
        email = 'pb@f.com',
        emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
        localesidkey = 'en_US',
        languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
        timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        alias='nuser',
        lastname='lastname',
        contactId = conCase.id
        );
        insert newUser1;

        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(newUser1) {
            String logoUrl = getLogo.getImage();
            System.assertEquals('testLogo', logoUrl);
        Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending if account query is in a List or not I'm getting either list.exception out of bound 0 or queryException nor rows for assignment.

Could you please help me with my tests ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to specify the line of code that is throwing the error, and in what specific situation does the error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you are getting Account by its ParentId.

```
 WHERE parentId = :u.Contact.AccountId];
```

In your test data insertion, you are not populating ParentId in your test data and that's why it is not able to find it. When you are inserting test data, account part should be like below.

```
Account parentAcc = new Account (
        Name = 'Parent Acc',
        Logo__c = 'testLogo',
        Sous_type__c = 'Groupe'
        );  
        insert parentAcc;

Account acc1 = new Account (
        Name = 'Child Acc',
        ParentId = parentAcc.Id,
        Sous_type__c = 'Groupe'
        );  
        insert acc1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I have tried it, and Im still getting a system.QueryException when running the test.

Comment: Are you trying to get parent of the parent account's Logo? Or just the User's Contact's Account's Parent Account's Logo? If so you also need to update your query from ParentId to Id.

Comment: Yes, getImage returns the account's parent Account's Logo - if I switch parentId for Id in the query Logo doesnt appear in my community page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, AccountId needed to be related to parent account not children:

```
 Contact conCase = new Contact (
    AccountId = parentAcc.id,
    LastName = 'portalTestUserv1'
    );
    insert conCase;
```

Tho creating both accounts was indeed needed, thanks.